# Get Provisioned and Used space details of VM using powershell

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine

I am having below code which is giving me data needed for one of my VM report

```
$vkcpw = Get-Content E:\vkcpw.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content E:\\V-center_aes.key)
$vcentercredential   = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("USER",$vkcpw)
Connect-VIServer -server 19.16.11.13 -Credential $vcentercredential
Connect-VIServer -server 12.16.18.5 -Credential $vcentercredential

Write-Host "Start"(Get-date)

$report = foreach($vc in $global:defaultviservers){


    foreach($vm in (Get-View -ViewType VirtualMachine -Property Name,runtime.powerState,runtime.consolidationNeeded,Guest.net,Config.Hardware.numCPU,Config.Hardware.MemoryMB,

    Runtime.Host,Guest.GuestFullName, Config.GuestFullName,Parent,ResourcePool,Config.Hardware.Device,Config.version,Config.Tools.ToolsVersion,guest.toolsversionstatus,

    Config.Files.VMPathName,Config.Template,Config.Hardware,Guest.HostName,Guest.Net,Runtime.Host -Server $vc )){

        if($vm.Config.Template){

            $t = Get-View -Id (Get-View $vm.Runtime.Host).Parent

        }

        else{

            $t = Get-View $vm.ResourcePool -Property Name,Parent -Server $vc

            while($t.getType().Name -eq "ResourcePool"){

              $t = Get-View $t.Parent -Property Name,Parent -Server $vc

            }

        }

        if($t.GetType().Name -eq "ClusterComputeResource"){

            $cluster = $t.Name

        }

        else{

            $cluster = "Stand Alone Host"

        }

        while($t.getType().Name -ne "Datacenter"){

            $t = Get-View $t.Parent -Property Name,Parent -Server $vc

        }

        $datacenter = $t.Name

        $VMtoGetSpace = Get-VM -Name $vm.Name

        $UsedSpaceInGB = [math]::Round($VMtoGetSpace.UsedSpaceGB,2)

        $ProvisionedSpaceGB = [math]::Round($VMtoGetSpace.ProvisionedSpaceGB,2)

        $vm.Config.Hardware.Device | where {$_ -is [VMware.Vim.VirtualDisk]} |

        Select @{N="VM";E={$vm.Name}},

        @{N='powerState';E={$vm.runtime.powerState}},

        @{N='IP';E={[string]::Join(',',($vm.Guest.Net | %{$_.IpAddress | where{$_.Split('.').Count -eq 4} | %{$_}}))}},

        @{N='NumCPU';E={$vm.config.Hardware.NumCpu}},

        @{N='Memory GB';E={$vm.Config.Hardware.MemoryMB| %{[math]::Round($_/1kb,2)}}},

        @{N='vCenter';E={$vc.Name}},

        @{N='VMHost';E={$script:esx = Get-View -Id $vm.Runtime.Host -Server $vc ; $script:esx.name}},

        @{N='GuestOS';E={$vm.Guest.GuestFullName}},

        @{N='ConfiguredOS';E={$vm.Config.GuestFullName}},

        #@{N="Folder";E={$path}},

        @{N="Cluster";E={$cluster}},

        @{N="Datacenter";E={$datacenter}}, 

        @{N="Disk datastore";E={$_.Backing.Filename.Split(']')[0].TrimStart('[')}},        

        @{N="Disk capacity GB";E={$_.CapacityInKB| %{[math]::Round($_/1MB,2)}}},       

      @{n="NumNICs"; e={(Get-NetworkAdapter -VM $vm.Name | Measure-Object).Count}}
      @{N='VMDKPath';E={$_.Backing.FileName}},

      @{N="HW Version";E={$vm.Config.version}},

      @{N="VMware Tools version";E={$vm.Config.Tools.ToolsVersion}},  

      @{N="Tools Status";E={$vm.guest.toolsversionstatus}}

      
          

    }

}

$report | Export-Csv E:\report.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture

Write-Host "end"(Get-date)
```

This is working fine but I have to add **Provisioned Space** and **Used Space** details also.

I tried the below code which is giving me the data but not getting how to add this code in this existing code

```
        $VMtoGetSpace = Get-VM -Name $vm.Name
        $UsedSpaceInGB = [math]::Round($VMtoGetSpace.UsedSpaceGB,2)
        $ProvisionedSpaceGB = [math]::Round($VMtoGetSpace.ProvisionedSpaceGB,2)
```

Please let me know how to add these 3 values in the existing code or if there is any other way to get the data

Comment: Just add these to the rest of the calculated properties in the `Select-Object` like `@{N="Provisioned Space GB";E={$ProvisionedSpaceGB}},
@{N="Used Space GB";E={$UsedSpaceInGB}}`

Comment: @Theo: Thanks for your response. let me check. will update you

Comment: @Theo: It worked fine. thanks. need one more help. when I am executing the script, for each `$vm`, it is writing the data multiple times. I am trying to find if there is any issue with closing braces or something. every time for each server it is going back to this line `$vm.Config.Hardware.Device | where {$_ -is [VMware.Vim.VirtualDisk]}`

Comment: All I can see is that this line: `@{n="NumNICs"; e={(Get-NetworkAdapter -VM $vm.Name | Measure-Object).Count}}` is missing a trailing comma, and I think this `$vm.Config.Hardware.Device | Where-Object {$_ -is [VMware.Vim.VirtualDisk]}` results in an array of VirtualDisks devices, so you will actually need to loop there. What if you write `@($vm.Config.Hardware.Device | Where-Object {$_ -is [VMware.Vim.VirtualDisk]})[0]` there to take only the first occurrence? Is your report then still complete?

Comment: @Theo: Yes, that trailing comma I fixed and for `@($vm.Config.Hardware.Device | Where-Object {$_ -is [VMware.Vim.VirtualDisk]})[0]` I am trying now. let me check the report and will let you know. Thanks